# iOS App Store: How to share analytics data of selected App Store / region?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have published an app on the iOS App Store which is available world wide. In App Store Connect I can see all kind of analytics data for this app (downloads, sales, etc.) for all different Stores / regions.

Is it somehow possible to give a partner limited access to the data of a specific region?

**Context:**

A company from the Netherlands offered to localize the App in dutch and to promote it. To measure the success they need access to the Dutch Store charts. Is it possible to give them access to the dutch data without including all other data?

I know that App Store Connect offers different user roles. While these limit the access to different features, I could not find any option to limit the access to different analytics data.

If App Store Connect does not offer this feature: Is there third-party service which could be used (App Annie, Appfollow, etc. does not as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to share specific data from App Analytics on App Store Connect. They will either have access to all the data or none. Not sure if 3rd party providers like AppAnnie or similar allow this, but it's not possible on App Store Connect.